# Why the src attribute in the amp-list always has to be HTTPS?

Tags: amp-html

In the AMP specification, it says that for `<amp_list>` the `src` attribute has to be HTTPS and CORS enabled.

AMP is all about mobile content and mobile articles so I don't understand why the host site has to be CORS enabled and HTTPS ?

Is it that because the AMP pages will be served from GOOGLE CACHE so it won't come from the same origin as the host/publisher site?

Please update if there is any info on the same.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, Google is only caching the images and HTML. So, since Google will be serving the cached AMP pages over HTTPS, all `src` attributes, except for `<amp-img>`, must be served over HTTPS as well otherwise you will have mixed content and the request will be blocked for security reasons when the page is loaded from the Google cache.